# Update to latest Polymer using Bower

Tags: json, bower, polymer-1.0

I have a Polymer application which is configured as following:

**My main project bower.json file**:

```
{
  "name": "Raf",
  "authors": [
    "Raffaeu <raffaeu@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "description": "Test Project",
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#1.2.0",
    "iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#^1.0.8",
    "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.7"
  }
}
```

and inside my **bower_components** folder I do have a **polymer** folder with the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "polymer",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "main": [
    "polymer.html"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "webcomponentsjs": "^0.7.2"
  }
}
```

Now, if I am in the root folder (*where the main bower.json file is located*) and I am running `bower info polymer` bower returns me the following list of versions:

```
bower cached        https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#1.6.0
bower validate      1.6.0 against https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#*

{
  name: 'polymer',
  version: '1.6.0',
   ...
```

But if I run `bower update polymer --save` console returns following message and doesn't update to 1.6.0 but it stays to my current version which is 1.2.0:
Unable to find a suitable version for polymer, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:

```
    1) polymer#1.2.0 which resolved to 1.2.0 and is required by MyTestProject
    2) polymer#~1.2.0 which resolved to 1.2.4 and is required by paper-datatable#0.9.8
    3) polymer#^1.2.0 which resolved to 1.6.0 and is required by iron-behaviors#1.0.13
    4) polymer#^1.2.1 which resolved to 1.6.0 and is required by paper-behaviors#1.0.11
    5) polymer#^1.2.4 which resolved to 1.6.0 and is required by iron-menu-behavior#1.1.3
    6) polymer#^1.1.1 which resolved to 1.6.0 and is required by vaadin-grid#1.0.0
    7) polymer#^1.0.0 which resolved to 1.6.0 and is required by iron-a11y-keys-behavior#1.1.1
    8) polymer#^1.1.0 which resolved to 1.6.0 and is required by paper-dropdown-menu#1.1.3

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer 1
```

And **nothing is updated**.
Should I manually change version to 1.6.0 inside the polymer folder then run update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to select `!3` this will add a new object in your `bower.json` called `resolutions` with value as `polymer#^1.2.0`. Using `!` will persist your choice in `bower.json`. As you are selecting first option it is taking the version from your `bower.json` which is set to use exact version i.e. `1.2.0`.

Actually, you can select anything after 3rd option as they all are `latest above` mentioned version `because of '^'`.